# Does S5 have subgroups isomorphic to D5 and D6?

Tags: group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions on Symmetric group of degree 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220697/questions-on-symmetric-group-of-degree-5)

I was told that $S_5$ has subgroups isomorphic to $D_5$ and $D_6$, however when I looked it up here I didn't see any mention of $D_6$? (I am presuming that $D_5$ is actually $D_10$ on this page, but there is no mention of a $D_12$). So does $S_5$ have subgroups isomorphic to $D_5$ and $D_6$?

And how would the generators of these subgroups relate to the elements of $S_5$?

Comment: Looked it up where?

Comment: Why did you feel the need to post this part of your previous question as a new question?

Comment: Subscripts only consist of the following item; if you want them to include more then one item, e.g. two digits, you need to enclose them in braces.